# Skype doesn't work with webcam A4Tech PK-130MG

Tags: skype, camera

I've just installed Mint 12 on a desktop previously running Windows Vista.

Despite using Ubuntu and Kubuntu on other machines, i still see myself as a beginner on GNU/Linux.

On this Mint 12 machine, I can't make Skype, nor GTalk, nor any msn protocol client recognize the webcam, which is a A4Tech PK-130MG.

I tried to install Ekiga, but the screen freezes at the first instant when the webcam is started.

Only Camorama was able to properly capture the image from webcam.

Nor Cheese, nor kamoso work. When anyone of them is started, the webcam image is showed for only an instant, after which the program crashes.

I've already tried, without sucess, the procedure described at http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/219

As nothing worked till now, i'm here asking for help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The link you refer deals with 32-bit libraries to support video in Skype. This is not your problem, yet.

According to this [discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1315760) it seems that your webcam is supported by **GSPCA** driver. Nevertheless you have to provide some more information related to issue:
`uname -a` # I don't even know if your system is 64-bit or 32-bit.
`lsusb` # I suppose your camera is usb from a picture.
`lsmod|grep gspca` # To make sure if the GSPCA driver is loaded.

You might also have a look at [Mandriva QC guide](http://wiki.mandriva.com/en/Logitech_Quickcam#One_Man.27s_Experience_with_the_Logitech.E2.84.A2_Quickcam_Connect). Even thou is different distro and different webcam it provides some useful information.

Comment: The webcam [info](http://www.a4tech.com/product.asp?cid=77&scid=162&id=437)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a tough nut to crack as Skype is closed source.

Honestly, webcam are so inexpensive these days I think it would be much less hassle to pick up a working webcam.

If you want to debug this, tell us more. Does the vid cam work outside of skype ? output of lspci -vvv (post only the section on your webcam)

Start skype from the command line, any errors ?

you can also try to debug with strace. If you do not understand strace, it is almost certainly more hassle then it is worth.